Bypass Certificate Verification in flutter with https?
I just want to bypass the certificate verification but I het the error that the badCertificateCallback is not defined for client. Do you know how can I make this work?
Thank you.
This is my actual code
http.Client client = http.Client();

 
    HttpClient() {
      // Load the PEM certificate file during class initialization
      loadCertificate();
      
  

    }


    Future<void> loadCertificate() async {
  // Load the certificate asset
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/certificate.pem');
  // Convert the ByteData to a List<int>
  List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  // Configure the default HTTP client to use the certificate
  SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
  securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(bytes);
  // Set the badCertificateCallback
    client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
      // Always trust the certificate
      return true;
    };`



Try using the .. cascade operator:
void main() async {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
    ..badCertificateCallback =
        ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

  HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse('https://your-url.com'));

  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

  // Handle your response...
}


This is what I use for configure_nonweb.dart
///allows calls to override a bad https certificate
///
///only used in non-web code
void overRideHttps() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
}

///ignore bad certificates
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) =>
      super.createHttpClient(context)
        ..badCertificateCallback =
            (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
}

In my main() function I call:
overRideHttps();
To import the file, I look to see if I'm using the web or not:
import 'unsupported.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'configure_nonweb.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'configure_web.dart';

in file unsupported.dart put:
void overRideHttps() {
  throw UnsupportedError('');
}

